# Adding date and time to systems tray in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, clock

The date and time don't show up in my Windows 7 systems tray.  I went into Control Panel and looked for answers. I increased the size of the task bar to see if it would pop up.  No luck.

Help please!

Comment: which resolution are you working on?

Answer (score 3):

- Right-click an empty space on the taskbar and then click **Properties**.
- Click the **Customize** button in the Notification area section of the Taskbar and Start Menu Properties window.
- Click **Turn system icons on or off** at the bottom left of the Notification Area Icons window.
- Set the Clock icon’s behavior to **On** and then click **OK** to save the changes.

Note: Time **and** Date can only be displayed in the notification area if you're using large Icons for the Taskbar. if you're using small icons, **only** the time will be shown, for a workaround, see my answer in this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/89628/windows-7-display-date-using-small-icons).

Comment: you're more than welcome.

Comment: @Tom: If your question is answered, you can mark this as the right response (the green thingy next to the votes on this response.

Answer (score 2):

Some alternatives for those who land here:

**[TClockEx](http://www.rcis.co.za/dale/tclockex/index.htm):**

- Freeware

  [image]

**[ClockDummy](http://www.dummysoftware.com/clockdummy.html):**

- Shareware

  [image]

**[Sarbyx TrayClock](http://www.rocketdownload.com/program/sarbyx-trayclock-24383.html):**

- Freeware

  [image]

**[Vista Clock](http://www.rocketdownload.com/program/vista-clock-120132.html)**:

- Freeware

  [image]

P.s. Now that we're talking about clocks. I just saw this one.... it's gorgeous, not really what you asked for (not for the system tray):

**[NOVACLOCK](http://www.novaclock.de/)**

[image]