# Windows 7: How to display both date and time in tray *without* using large icons or increasing the height of taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, date-time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 - display date using small icons](https://superuser.com/questions/89628/windows-7-display-date-using-small-icons)

As we approach the year 2012, there has to be a way to show the date *and* time in Windows 7 *without* doing any of the following:

- Increasing the height of the taskbar
- Using large icons
- Messing with the system date/time display format
- Third-party software

I've read a few answers here on StackExchange and they're a few years old, so I am hoping that, since that time, new options have been discovered.

Comment: The default on all my Windows 7 computers allows for this.  I use the smallest icon size possible, and have changed any of the settings, from their default.

Comment: Is your taskbar a single line or did you unlock the taskbar and drag up its height?

Comment: I agree with @Ramhound. Windows 7 default does what you ask. Even the Windows Basic theme shows date and time. Did you already change something?

Comment: He has it set to "Small Icons", so the date doesn't show. The problem is he wants the date, but doesn't want to un-check "Use small icons".  His restrictions make @surfasb's answer the only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the taskbar to the left or right hand side of the screen. This is generally a better position for the taskbar anyways, since vertical real estate is precious on these widescreens.

Comment: Marked as answer to get my answer ratio up since no one else can add new answers to this anyway.